# Как определить смену тенденции временного ряда?

Tags: статистика, временные-ряды

Мне интересен инструмент, с помощью которого можно оценивать изменение временных рядов. Допустим, есть временной ряд, представляющий собой зависимость виброускорения от времени. Датчик, который преобразует виброускорения в сигнал, расположен на некой машине. Нужно, используя данные датчика, понять когда машина работала, а когда была в покое. Как это реализовать при помощи математики?

Comment: Вообще нужно больше данных, но, кажется, смотрят разницу между соседними измерениями. А потом ещё разницу между этими разницами. Но без конкретных данных это всё абстрактно. Измерения могут быть с пропусками, могут скакать туда-сюда, их надо сглаживать, в общем, нужно больше данных, чтобы предметно говорить.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что это отдельное и очень непростое направление в рамках теории временных рядов.  И весьма объемное, хотя и не столь модное, как forecasting.  Может появляться под "псевдонимами" "change point detection", "обнаружение разладок", "Structural Instability", "Time Series Segmentation Procedures", "Novelty Detection" и еще пол десятка других. Изучается с разных сторон и в технической диагностике, и в эконометрике, в анализе сигналов, в системах обнаружения сетевых атак  и еще в нескольких прикладных доменов. Веер методов, которые тут используются -  от специальным образом сформулированных статистических гипотез до нейросетей. Об этом можно писать очень долго, тем более, что это направление то, чем мне приходится в основном заниматься последние лет пять. Но подменять книги форумом - не хочется. Поэтому дам несколько ссылочек - а далее как обычно, задавайте конкретные вопросы, когда появятся.

Классика:

1. [Никифоров И.В. Последовательное обнаружение изменения свойств временных рядов](https://www.twirpx.com/file/221797/)
2. [Бассвиль М. Обнаружение изменения свойств сигналов и динамических систем](https://www.twirpx.com/file/324794/)
3. [Н. Клигене, Л. Телькснис, Методы обнаружения момен-
   тов изменения свойств случайных процессов](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=at&paperid=5224&option_lang=rus)

Некоторые последние обзоры:

> https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10115-016-0987-z
> https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/01621459.2017.1385466
> https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.06222
> https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335937522_Selective_review_of_offline_change_point_detection_methods
>
> https://www.mdpi.com/2225-1146/3/1/156

Диссертации:

https://www.db-thueringen.de/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/dbt_derivate_00028473/ilm1-2013000513.pdf

и т.д.

Удачи.